# Typescript - 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.(2683)

Tags: typescript, constructor

I'm using the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), how can I write the following code in the playground without the error on `this` keyword?

```js
const MyNode = function (val?:number, next?:unknown) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = next;
}
```

I tried putting this above the function, but it doesn't seem to work

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 * @this typeof MyNode
 */
```

Comment: See [this params](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @caTS for the reference. The code below works.

```js
interface IMyNode {
    val: number;
    next?: IMyNode;
}

const MyNode = function (this:IMyNode, val:number, next?:IMyNode) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = next;
}
```